# List owner processes of open file handles in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-descriptor

I'm currently getting an "out of handles" error in my Event Viewer for a program.

**What would be a good program to list what processes are using file handles?**

An example would be 'lsof' in the *nix world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use processexplorer

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

From the introduction:

> The top window always shows a list of the currently active processes, including the names of their owning accounts, whereas the information displayed in the bottom window depends on the mode that Process Explorer is in: if it is in handle mode you'll see the handles that the process selected in the top window has opened

The handle mode is the one you're interested in.

For Chrome on my box I see for example:

[image: PE handlemode spit]

You can also search for a handle by name.

Comment: To expand on @rene's answer, you can list each processes handle count as one of the columns. You can also double-click a process and view it's Performance tab for more detailed handle counts, or press Ctrl+H to show the handles owned by the selected process in detail (name, type, etc.) Finally, you can search for a specific handle if you know part of it's name (e.g. the file's name for a file handle) by pressing Ctrl+F. Related reading: [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Handle tool from SysInternals.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The command line tool Handle.exe tool of sysinternal lists all handles of (all) processes, lists processes of file name pattern etc. If your search-index is not a particular process, I prefer this above the GUI program Process Explorer of same authors.

Answer (score 0):

In this question on Unix SE [How to get over “device or resource busy”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11238/1806) OP mention that he use [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/downloadnow.htm) on Windows. It's great tool, just right click on file or directory and find the process that locking it and you can delete or unlock it with single click.